# How to angle a image with a div that fits inside the image

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I need to find a solution to keep the cropped image but have content sit inside with an opacity filter on the div. The problem I'm facing is that it wont match the angles and i cant use an overlap hidden, need to find a solution.... can anyone help with this shame you cant use an ::after on image to add filter div to darken a section  :(

```css
.promo {
  position: relative;
}

.promo img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 16%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 84%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 16%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 84%);
}

.promo__content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100% color: #fff;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/600/600.jpg" >
  <div class="promo__content">
    Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Example of what I'm trying to do black box in the angled image the black box will be see through

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the clip-path to the whole container and not only the image to get what you want:

```css
.container {
  margin:50px 0;
  clip-path:polygon(0 16%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 84%);
  display:flex;
}
.box {
  width:30%;
  padding:80px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
}
.img {
  width:70%;
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/1000/1000.jpg) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      some text here<br>
      some text here<br>
      some text here<br>
      some text here<br>
      some text here<br>
    </div>
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Amazing thank you so much !! can stop sratching the head on this one thanks